# Проблема рендеринга в многомодульном приложении с Moxy, Fragment и несколькими Toolbar

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, toolbar, render

Приложение содержит несколько модулей, используется Moxy, Fragment, RecyclerView, Toolbar. 
Основной тулбар был прикручен к MainActivity и всё работало. При добавлении в один из модулей второго тулбара возникла проблема рендеринга: "Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme" и предупреждение: "Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references."

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Гугление дало несколько ссылок которые не помогли:

- [Android Material Design: Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984183/android-material-design-failed-to-find-style-toolbarstyle-in-current-theme);
- [Material design: Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685914/material-design-failed-to-find-style-toolbarstyle-in-current-theme);
- [Android error - Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917936/android-error-failed-to-find-style-toolbarstyle-in-current-theme)

## module_00_lib\src\main\res\layout\module_00_fragment_recycler_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.example.module_00_lib.ui.fragment.recycler.RecyclerListFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/goods_toolbar"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvList"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## module_00_lib\src\main\res\layout\goods_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/goodsToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

## ui_app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.users_interface">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".model.UIApp"
        tools:replace="android:name"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## _service_lib\src\main\res\values\styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <!-- Toolbar styles -->
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>
    </style>
<!--Search widget theme.-->
    <style name="AppSearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <item name="queryBackground">@color/colorContrast</item>
        <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/search_24dp</item>
        <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/close_24dp</item>
        <item name="queryHint">@string/search_hint</item>
        <item name="android:imeActionId">6</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Зависимости между библиотеками заданы так:

- ui_app зависит от shell_lib и _service_lib;
- shell_lib зависит от нескольких модулей библиотек и от _service_lib;
- все модули библиотек зависят от _service_lib.

### Внимание! Вопрос!

Где и как нужно исправить, чтобы проблема рендеринга и жалобы на тему исчезли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если тема активити кастомная, то следует ее выбрать в просмоторщике из Manifest themes

[image: скриншот вьювера]

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало! +1